Cyclic modules are quotients by principal ideals?
In reading through Aluffi, Ch. 6, there is a proof of the following Lemma:
Let $R$ be an integral domain. Assume that every cyclic $R$-module is torsion-free. Then $R$ is a field.
The proof begins by choosing a cyclic $R$-module $R/(c)$ with $c$ $\in$ $R$ nonzero. I know that cyclic modules are quotients, but are all the ideals that give us these cyclic modules necessarily principal? Why?
It seems that the author is only showing the result for cyclic $R$-modules which are quotients by principal ideals, and not for arbitrary cyclic modules.

The claim is not that every cyclic module is of this form. The hypothesis is that every cyclic $R$-module satisfies some condition, so in particular these cyclic modules do.

This is a matter of logic.
If the conclusion of the theorem were of the form "Every cyclic $R$-module has property X", in order to prove that conclusion the author would have to consider every possible cyclic $R$-module. But when the assumption of the theorem is "Every cyclic $R$-module is torsion-free", the author is totally allowed to only use this assumption for a subset of all possible cyclic $R$-modules, particularly those of the form $R/(c)$.
You are not obliged to use the assumptions "to their fullest" when proving a theorem.
